# add posts in middle of html content in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, post

I tried to add posts in middle of my homepage content

this is my code for front-page.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p><?php _e('Sorry, this page does not exist.'); ?></p>
    <?php endif;

        $allPosts = new WP_Query('cat=5&posts_per_page=2');
        if ($allPosts -> have_posts()):
            while($allPosts -> have_posts()) : $allPosts -> the_post();
    ?>      <div class="container">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <hr>
            </div>
    <?php
            endwhile;

        else:

        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

What I got is like this

> ---header---
>
> ---html-content---
>
> ---**list-of-posts**---
>
> ---footer---

what I tried to get is like this

> ---header---
>
> ---html-content---
>
> ---**list-of-posts**---
>
> ---html-content---
>
> ---footer---

Is there a way to get list of posts in middle of html content?

Comment: Where is your html content , inside your post you printed in line 2-8?

Comment: the html content is after the get_header code @batz

Answer (score 0):

You should put the content you want under the list of posts in a separate post the print it by the ID under the list of posts.

Something like:

```
$my_postid = 12;//This is page id or post id
$content_post = get_post($my_postid);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;
```

If you don't want the post to be with your regular posts, create a special post-type. You could use [CPT ui](https://he.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) for it.